# How do I add Google Analytic to my WordPress site without using plugin?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have a script like

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    try{ 
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("xx-xxxxxxx-x");
    pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch(err) {} 
    </script>
```

So how do i use it works in my site? Please help me to get the solution..

Comment: That is some seriously outdated analytics code and should, in this day and age, not be used at all. And if you add it to the header it might block the rendering of your page until the google code is loaded (which is why Google introduced asychnronous code), so if you must use it put it in the footer.

Comment: thanks for your usable suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    try{ 
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("xx-xxxxxxx-x");
    pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch(err) {} 
    </script>
```

Add this snippet in the `header.php or head.php` in your files, just before the end of the `</head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Appearance>Widgets and add "Custom HTML" to any of your sidebar widgets and past the code in there.

Make sure to including the:

```
<script>...</script>
```